# Modify autoArrangeFigures (from Matlab File Exchange) to send different plots to different monitors

Tags: matlab, position, monitor, figure

Using

```
autoArrangeFigures(0,0,2); % (0,0,x) where x is monitor ID
```

one can choose where all figures are to be placed. I would like, however, to control which figures go to which monitor.

MWE attempt:

```
close all; clear all; clc

% make 10 figures
for i=1:10
    figure()
end

autoArrangeFigures(0,0,2); % (0,0,x) where x is monitor ID

pause(2)

% make 10 figures
for i=1:10
    figure()
end

autoArrangeFigures(0,0,1); % (0,0,x) where x is monitor ID
```

This only redirects all 20 figures to new monitor position. It doesn't keep the 10 figure positions from the first call of autoArrangeFigures(0,0,2) in monitor 2, but redirects all 10+10 figures to monitor 1 via autoArrangeFigures(0,0,1).

How to fix this?

autoArrangeFigures can be found at:

https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48480-automatically-arrange-figure-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you could do is modify the `autoArrangeFigures` function to take an additional (optional) argument `figHandles`.

Modify the first line to:

```
function autoArrangeFigures(NH, NW, monitor_id, figHandle)
```

To make this argument optional, you can change line 39

```
figHandle = sortFigureHandles(findobj('Type','figure'));
```

into

```
if ~exist('figHandle', 'var') || isempty(figHandle)
    figHandle = sortFigureHandles(findobj('Type','figure'));
else
    figHandle = figHandle(:); % make row vector
end
```

So then your MWE would look like:

```
clear fig
% make 10 figures
for i=1:10
    fig(i) = figure();
end
autoArrangeFigures(0,0,2, fig); % (0,0,x) where x is monitor ID

% make 10 figures
for i=1:10
    fig(10+i) = figure();
end
autoArrangeFigures(0,0,1,fig(11:20)); % (0,0,x) where x is monitor ID
```

Personally, I am a fan of [`distFig`](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37176-distribute-figures) from the Matlab FEX, which allows what you want out of the box.

Example:

```
for i = 1:20
    fig(i) = figure();
end
distFig('screen', 'Secondary', 'only', 1:10) % place only fig 1:10 on the secondary screen
distFig('screen', 'Primary', 'only', 11:20) % place only fig 11:20 on the primary screen
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested, incl. changing function autoArrangeFigures(NH, NW, monitor_id, figHandle), but it still generates same result as the original MWE.

Comment: Another thing; does distFig support 3 monitors?

Comment: @Ole I see, I made a mistake in the change to `autoArrangeFigures`, see the update. `distFig` does support multiple monitors, read the help to see how to select a monitor.